# Adding char*'s to a char**

Tags: c

I am trying to make a shell in c, and am trying to put what the user inputs into an array of strings (char **). My problem is that if, for example the user inputs "pwd", then "ls" in the next loop, both elements in history become ls. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 char **history = calloc(MAXARGS, sizeof(char*)); //MAXARGS = 128
 int histCounter = 0;
 char *commandline = calloc(MAX_CANON, sizeof(char));

 while(go) {  //exits loop when you type exit

    if (fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
              len = (int) strlen(buffer);
        buffer[len-1] = '\0';   
        strcpy(commandline, buffer);
    }

  history[histCounter] = commandline;

  if(histCounter > 0) {    //just to see if they are different
        printf("%s\n", history[histCounter-1]);
        printf("%s\n", history[histCounter]);
    }   
  histCounter = histCounter + 1;
  }
```

Comment: All entries in `history[...]` are equal to `commandline`. The value of `commandline` doesn't change in the loop.

Comment: Im sorry, im alittle confused. I thought it changes everytime the while loop executes. For example, the first run of the while loop I input "pwd" into fgets which makes commandline equal to "pwd"? Then the second time the while loop goes around I input "ls" into fgets. So wouldn't commandline change from "pwd" to "ls"?

Comment: `commandline` is just a pointer. What changes is the bytes it points to (the dynamic segment allocated by `calloc`). But all elements of `history` point to that same segment.

Comment: You have allocated the buffer for `commandline` only once. And all instances of `history[..]` always point to that same `commandline`. You need to allocate memory for `commandline` for every iteration of `while`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like:

```
history[hisCounter] = calloc(MAX_CANON, sizeof(char));
strcpy(history[hisCounter], commandline);
```

Or better yet, look into linked lists and use that instead.

Comment: Why linked lists?

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the problem! Also, Im alittle confused why I have to calloc memory inside memory that is already calloc'd.

Comment: because you allocated space for commandline, but then you want to save each copy of it in the history, so each copy needs its own space allocated.